# ConTeXt: Introduce columnsets around chapters

Tags: context, columns, layout

## Background

The following screen shot shows four uneven columns, which is the desired result:

[image: Uneven Columns]

## Problem

The `beforesection` and `aftersection` options to the `setuphead` command don't seem to have any effect, which results in the following:

[image: Unresponsive beforesection and aftersection options]

## Code

Reproduce the problem using:

```
\usemodule[newcolumnsets]

\definecolumnset[BookColumns][n=4]
\setupcolumnset[BookColumns:1][width=6in]
\setupcolumnset[BookColumns:2][width=4in]
\setupcolumnset[BookColumns:3][width=4in]
\setupcolumnset[BookColumns:4][width=4in]

\setuphead[chapter][
  beforesection={\startcolumnset[BookColumns]},
  aftersection={\stopcolumnset},
]

\definepapersize[BookPaperSize][
  width=24in,
  height=12in,
]

\setuppapersize[BookPaperSize]

\starttext
  \chapter[title={Chapter Title}]

  \dorecurse{5}{\input knuth \input lorem}
\stoptext
```

The uneven columns can be generated by changing the body to use `\startcolumnset` and `\stopcolumnset` directly:

```
  \startcolumnset[BookColumns]
    \chapter[title={Chapter Title}]

    \dorecurse{5}{\input knuth \input lorem}
  \stopcolumnset
```

## Ideas

I tried redefining the `chapter` element as:

```
\let\oldchapter\chapter
\unexpanded\def\chapter{\dosingleempty\newchapter}
\def\chapter[#1]{\startcolumnset[BookColumns]\oldchapter[#1]\stopcolumnset}
```

This did not work. What does work is a series of `sed` calls:

```
sed -i 's/^\\chapter\(.*\)/\\stopcolumnset\n\\startcolumnset[BookColumns]\n\\chapter\1/' body.tex
sed -i '1d' body.tex
echo "\\stopcolumnset" >> body.tex
```

Calling `sed` is not the "ConTeXt way", of course.

A different question shows using `beforesection` and `aftersection` with `mixedcolumns`:

```
\setuphead[subsection][
  beforesection={\startmixedcolumns[n=2,balance=no,]},
  aftersection={\stopmixedcolumns},
  page=no,
]
```

## Question

How would you ensure that the `\startcolumnset` and `\stopcolumnset` commands bracket every chapter without modifying the body? (That is, apply column sets for each chapter only by changing the setups.)

## Related

Related questions include:

- https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/129356/2148
- https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/160544/2148

Comment: For `beforesection` and `aftersection` you have to use `\startchapter` and `\stopchapter` instead of `\chapter`.

Comment: Yes, you can generate `\start...\stopsection` with pandoc.  I implemented this because you asked me to do it at some point: https://github.com/jgm/pandoc/pull/4295

Comment: You also need `\setuplayout[grid=yes]` for the new columnsets.  Otherwise floats will be misplaced and column balancing breaks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The sections must be balanced with `\start` and `\stop` commands (such as `\startsection` and `\stopsection` or `\startchapter` and `\stopchapter`) before using the `beforesection` and `aftersection` options. For example:

```
\setuphead[section][
  beforesection={\startcolumnset[BookColumns]},
  aftersection={\stopcolumnset},
]
```

When using pandoc's top-level-division option, it produces `\chapter` commands:

```
pandoc --top-level-division=chapter ...
```

By changing the command-line argument to `--section-divs`, pandoc produces `\startsection`, `\startsubsection`, `\startsubsubsection` and equivalent `\stop` commands:

```
pandoc --section-divs ...
```

Combining the two arguments produces `\startchapter` and `\stopchapter`, which also allows `beforesection` and `aftersection` to work:

```
pandoc --top-level-division=chapter --section-divs ...
```